# Dividing a string in groups of two

Tags: string, vb.net, grouping, divide

I have a Hex string that has a value like

> 26C726F026C426A1269A26AB26F026CC26E226C726E226CD

I was wondering how to split it into a string array, where each index of the array holds a group of 2 of those chars.

Example:
string(0)=26,string(1)=C7,string(2) = 26,string (3) = F0, and so on.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim MyList as New List(Of String)
Dim s as String = "26C726F026C426A1269A26AB26F026CC26E226C726E226CD"

For x as Integer = 0 to  s.Length - 1 step 2
  MyList.Add(s.substring(x,2))
Next
```

You can get it with **MyList(0), MyList(1)** or etc